# How to store a sql database connection pool in Firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

On first invocation of the Firebase function I create a mysql connection pool (which is expensive) and store it in global scope. This works fine as long as there is a single instance serving requests. Assuming multiple functions instances can exist under load, what's a good practice to prevent numerous such pools from getting created?

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific section in the Cloud Functions documentation: "[Use global variables to reuse objects in future invocations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations)".

> There is no guarantee that the state of a Cloud Function will be preserved for future invocations. **However, Cloud Functions often recycles the execution environment of a previous invocation**. If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.
>
> This way you can cache objects that may be expensive to recreate on
> each function invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud functions scale up to 1,000 instances per region.

SQL connections scale up to 32,000+.

Practically speaking, you're not going to run into upper limits on your db connection(s).